# style in xhtml is not added firsttime in jsf

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to append a style

```
<style>.requested {background: #9391ba;color:#000000}.accepted {background: #eb17eb;color:#000000}.completed {background: #ccc;color:#000000}.cancelled {background: #d7d7db;color:#000000}.cancelledwithpenalty {background: #ccc;color:#000000}</style>
```

The values changes from the server side, so i am setting it to a managedbean property and using it in the xhtml as

```
<h:outputText value="#{serviceCalendarViewBean.employeeStyleClass}" escape="false" />
```

When i change the value of employeeStyleClass and reload the page the new style is not loaded. If i refresh the page again the new style is loaded.
Is there a way to refresh the style when the page loads?
I have given the outputtext in the h:head and h:body but first time it is not loaded

Comment: Could you show us your whole code please ?

Comment: The employeeStyleClass property was not set with the new value. After setting this value the code worked.